# Reshape a [N x 2] table by grouping by values of the second column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following two-column table in a variable called `table` in a Jupyter Notebook:

| diag | al |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 4.0 |
| 1 | 2.0 |
| ... | ... |
| 0 | 0.0 |

where the first column ("diag") has 399 cells with 0's and 1's and the second column ("al") has 399 cells with values 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0.

I would like to do the following with Pandas in Python:

| 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The idea is that the code should look for all the rows that have 0.0 in "al" and list all the values of "diag" for 0.0 (e.g. [0,0,0,1,0,...]), same for 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0.

How can I do this using the library Pandas from Python?